# Is it possible to filtre on IP address for Azure STORAGE SAS with ACCESS POLICY?

Tags: azure, security, azure-storage-account

On azure storage sas you can filter IP address (allowed IP Filter)
for sas with access policy, I do not see how to do that. If possible, how please?

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem in more details? Are you trying to create an access policy that has IP address filtering? Please edit your question and provide details there only (and not in comments).

Comment: Not by using the Access Policy. This has to be done either by using the SAS token or via Azure Storage firewall settings     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Mantri , thanks SumanthMarigowda-MSFT, this answers my question